# How can I achieve over 1 million hash rates with minergate?

Tags: cpu-mining

When I check minergate top 5 miner list for monero, it says the top miner has 1,976,941 H/s speed whereas I can only get ~270 H/s on CPU.

I also read somewhere that GPU mining for cryptonight algorithm makes it x2 faster or so but not like x100 faster so I don't think it is because of the GPUs that miner may have. (Also it can be some bad information but I'm not sure)

So my question is how to achieve that kind of speed? With what kind of hardware and which miner? I think the answers from the last year are not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Please avoid Minergate, since they are stealing some of your hash rate.

You will probably never be able to achieve 1MH/s on Cryptonight with a single machine, but multiple mining rigs or a botnet with dozens of hijacked machines mining into your account. But better avoid that, too.

Comment: But aren't multiple mining rigs or botnet machines increasing the workers but not the speed?
Also; could you direct me a place where I can find wallet suggestions than? Or could you suggest one? I mean, I use minergate becuase it's a combination of pool and a wallet to me. So I don't have to find a good pool and wallet. So I'm all ears on suggestions.

Comment: More workers is more speed and it will be accumulated.

Freewallet = Minergate and both can steal your money, since you are not holding your keys.

Best wallet is the official GUI from GetMonero.org but you can also use other solutions, where you hold your keys like web based MyMonero.com or Monerujo.io on Android. The official GUI is being ported to mobile, both Android and iOS already, but is not ready yet.

Comment: I chose my pool and set up my wallet. I still can't understand how to achieve higher speeds as even 109 KH/s for example. I guess that you can use a proxy to merge your miners as one miner so your collaborative speed is higher. However, where can I find the correct hardware for this speed? Are mining rigs for BTC or ETHER also good for Monero? Because considering the algorithm change, they look like overpriced for Monero mining.

Comment: Bitcoin is being mined with special ASICs just being able to create sha256 hashes but at a much higher rate than usual hardware, so they are useless for Monero. However, Ethereum is mainly mined on GPU rigs and they can easily also be used for mining Monero. You will find more information about hashrates of current hardware on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/